# Wordpress Image Editor issue in IE7

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer-7

Anyone knows why WP Image Editor is not working in IE7? IE7 would just crash every time I click on the Edit Image button.

I do not see this problem in other browsers, only IE7.

I tested using WP 3.4 and the latest 3.4.1 and get the same result.

Any idea how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: I always hate seeing answers like 'don't use IE7' to questions like this but in this case it's fair. You can't control which browser your users access your site with but you can control the ones your admins use. Tell the admins they have to use a modern browser, thats what I would do.

Comment: I wish I could, my client uses IE7 for their internal usage and I'm left with no choice than to fix this issue. However, it's a pretty bad thing because that image editor will just kill the browser. I'm curious to find out what's the logical reason behind this issue.

Comment: FYI, my client is a government organization and they have strict policies so it's almost impossible to ask them to upgrade / modify their browsers. Oh geez!

Comment: Ah!  You have my sympathies.  Good luck with it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit:

I was wrong about IE7 deprecation in admin.  I also was able to confirm the crash using a virtual machine with IE9 set to IE7 document and IE7 standards mode.

Updating one of the external libraries fixes the issue on my end.  See the updated ticket for the patch.  Could you please test this patch and see if it resolves the issue for you.

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18199

Update wp-includes/js/imgareaselect/jquery.imgareaselect.js with the updated version from github to test.

https://github.com/odyniec/imgareaselect/blob/master/jquery.imgareaselect.dev.js

Comment: That's a bad news. Yes I've tried that and the problem still exists.

Comment: I was wrong about IE7 deprecation.  I also believe I fixed the bug.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Chris, that looks promising. Btw, I'm the one created the ticket #21348 in Wordpress, so I'll monitor the fix and update again later on.

Comment: Just to confirm that your fix works like a charm. Thanks Chris!

Comment: Awesome. They have it tagged for 3.4.2 release.